# Very low speed in executing Rails commands

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, command-prompt

I have a strange problem in rails:
When I type a command in cmd like "rails server" or "rake db:schema:dump" and press ENTER , the time last to cmd give me the result of my command is very long( almost 3 or 4 minutes ).
Please help me to solve this problem and I can give the result of command in a few second.
thanks.

---

my system :
***CPU*** : Intel Core 2 Due T9300 2.5GHz
***RAM*** : 4GB
***OS*** : Window 7( 64-bit )
***Ruby*** Version : 1.9.2p290
***Rails*** Version : 3.1.3

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem on Windows, that's cause Ruby is very slow on Win.
You can try Cygwin, it was little more faster for me.
[Why is ruby so much slower on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920201/why-is-ruby-so-much-slower-on-windows)