# Rails Startup Latency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Using Rails 3.1.3--rails console takes about 45 seconds to start up and display the prompt; rake takes about the same to start executing; once underway, commands seem to be executed at a "normal" speed.  Running on Win XP, fully updated.  (New to Ruby and RoR)

What are possible causes of this startup latency?

Comment: See previously asked question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920201/why-is-ruby-so-much-slower-on-windows

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using, and is it the RubyInstaller version?

Answer (score 0):

It's usual situation for Windows platforms.

Check your antivirus, add `ruby.exe` to exception list and then antivirus will not trace what ruby is doing on your machine.