# Rails deployment using thin on windows vs linux

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, thin

when I'm deploying my rails application on thin over linux, it works good

BUT when over Windows, it's pretty slow, and I feel like it's not working concurrently!!

do I need to make something different to make it works good over windows???

my application is hitting a set of databases pretty much, either the project's DB where it uses active record or even another databases using Mysql2

Answer (score 0):

Ruby is slow when running under windows. Also take a look at this topic for a detailed explanation:
[Why is ruby so much slower on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920201/why-is-ruby-so-much-slower-on-windows)

Basically, most best practices for achieving higher performance in any other environment do apply, but running Rails on Windows will probably never be faster than running it on Linux. Ruby 1.9.3 will be faster than 1.8.7, so if you're still running 1.8.7, that could be a start.

Comment: but I didn't reach that point ,they are about 3-5 users and it's sometimes behave like there is no concurrency!!

Comment: What do you mean when you're saying there is no concurrency? What kind of server are you running? If you compare Passenger on Linux with Webrick on Windows for example, the difference will be huge.

Comment: I'm not using webrick, by no concurrency, here you this example: I'm loading several iframes when the rails app is deployed on linux, they are finished loading asynchronously, each may take a long time or a little, BUT on windows, they are all finish loading together!!!

Comment: That sounds pretty concurrent to me ;) Maybe someone who has a little more experience with running Rails on Windows in production can chip in, but I doubt there are many. Ruby is optimized for Linux, not for Windows.